# Palindromic Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, palindromic-polynomials

What are the steps to solve this and what is the goal?

$$ax^6 + bx^5 + cx^4 + dx^3 + cx^2 + bx + a$$

Comment: What do you mean by solve?

Comment: Should there be an $=0$ at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x=0$ is not a solution, so we can write
$$a(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3})+b(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})+c(x+\frac{1}{x})+d=0$$
and substitute $$t=x+\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Given: $x^6+ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+bx^2+ax+1=0$

Assuming a root's inverse is not conjugate, then it must one of four related roots that satisfy the quartic

$$x^4+ax^3+bx^2+ax+1$$

If $a^2-4b+8\gt 0$, the quartic may be split into two palindromic quadratics.